# Bug in "suggested edits" review list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

While going into the "review" tab, to review items, I noticed this:

> [image: Screenshot]

It explicitly specifies that a user needs **at least** 1k rep to approve or reject "Suggested Edits". It says that [Andrea](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/2770/andrea-carrer) made **2** suggested edits today.

Is that a bug, or an exploit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To suggest an edit and to approve an edit are two different things.

Anyone can suggest an edit (even without an account). These suggested edits are then waiting in the review list until approved by either :

- two different users with 1k reputation (2k on a graduated site)
- the owner of the post which was edited
- or a moderator

Those users can reject, accept or improve a suggested edit by adding their own changes. The latter action removes the edit from the queue immediately and two separate sets of changes are added to the history of the post.

In this case Andrea **accepted** two suggested edits to **his own** post (improving one of those two suggested edits).

Comment: Thanks that answers to my question. Didn't know that you could accept a suggested edit to your own post.